# Sorting wp_query by custom post type, meta field and publish date

Tags: wordpress

We have a "resource library" on our web site which features upcoming webinars, on-demand (past) webinars, blogs, case studies and other resources. When someone comes to the resource library, it needs to list the upcoming webinars first in chronological order by a meta field called "date_start" THEN all the other resources in reverse chronological order by **publish date**. BOTH upcoming and on-demand webinars have this meta field called "date_start". This field is populated for upcoming webinars but is blank in on-demand webinars.

Here's the code which creates the query that populates the resource library. It contains other args for when the user filters by taxonomy or post type. I've called out the section which is most relevant to my question.

```
    public function change_query( $query ){
        if( empty( $this->relationship ) ) return;
        
        if ( $query->is_main_query() and ( $query->is_home() or $query->is_category() ) ) {
            // post_type start
            $key = 'filter_resource_types';
            if( isset( $this->relationship[ $key ] ) ){
                $values = $this->get_current_values( $key );
                $post_types = array_keys( $this->filter_resource_types() );
                if( $values ){
                    $temp = [];
                    
                    foreach( $values as $value ){
                        if( $this->is_cheked( $value, $post_types ) ) {
                            $temp[] = $value;
                        }
                    }

                    if( $temp ){
                        $post_types = $temp;
                    }
                }
   
                $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
            }
            // post_type end

            // tax_query start
            $tax_query = [];
            $taxonomies = [
                'filter_solutions' => 'f_solutions',
                'filter_topics' => 'f_topics',
                'filter_roles' => 'f_roles',
            ];

            foreach( $taxonomies as $key => $taxonomy ){
                if( isset( $this->relationship[ $key ] ) ){
                    $values = $this->get_current_values( $key );
                    if( $values ){
                        $tax_query[] = [
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $values,
                            'operator' => 'AND'
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }

            if( count( $tax_query ) > 1 ){
                $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
            }

            if( $tax_query ){
                $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            }
            // tax_query end

            // posts_per_page
            $per_page = 11;
            if ( $query->is_category() and isset( $_GET['section'] ) ) {
                $per_page = 3;
            } elseif( isset( $_GET[ 'json' ] ) ){
                $per_page = -1;// test
            }

            //**** This is the section where I need help *****


            // Here I do a meta query to include all posts whether the date_start
            // meta field exists or not. This way, I can use this field for ordering the result.

            $query->set( 'meta_query',array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                        'key'=>'date_start',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                // EXISTS array must be in the end.
                array(
                        'key'=>'date_start',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                )
                ));

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );

            // Now I order the results first by the date_start (meta_value_num) and then
            // by publish date.

            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num date' );
        }
    }
```

In the template file where I display the results, I do a quick usort so I can put the upcoming webinars in chronological order by date_start:

```
usort($wp_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
   return strcasecmp( 
      $a->date_start, 
      $b->date_start 
   );
});
```

Once this is done, I get the upcoming webinars in chronological order but right after them comes ALL of the on-demand webinars even though they don't have the date_start field populated. I believe this is because, even though the field isn't populated, the fact that it exists for the on-demand webinar post type means it gets sorted next after the upcoming webinars. Then finally (after scrolling through all 200 on-demand webinars) I get all the other resource types in reverse chronological order.

SO... my question is: what's the best way to make it so the upcoming webinars are sorted chronologically by date_start and the on-demand webinars and other resources are all sorted by publish date? Is there a way to tweak my code or is a totally different approach called for?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Welcome! I wouldn't tackle this with a single `WP_Query` - also looks like you're using `pre_get_posts` here as well - which may not be your best option. I would personally build two separate queries for this - Webinars and then everything else, pop the results into an array and then output. Update your post with this info: what are Webinars, Case Studies, etc? Post types, Taxonomies? How are these being output - on a page template? Archive page?